# Multiple-thread access by Jersey client 2.25.1 with HTTPS(Certificate)

Tags: java, multithreading, ssl, jersey-client

I meet a problem while using "javax.ws.rs.client.Client(Jersey client 2.25.1)" to send https request in multiple-thread context.

1) First I create a client like following:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().sslContext(createSSLContext()).build();

private static SSLContext createSSLContext() throws Exception {
    SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContext.getInstance(TLS);
    KeyManagerFactory kmf = 
    KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    try (InputStream keyStoreSteam = new FileInputStream(keystoreFile)) {
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        ks.load(keyStoreSteam, keystorePwd.toCharArray());
        kmf.init(ks, keystorePwd.toCharArray());
    }
    try (InputStream trustStoreSteam = new FileInputStream(trustStoreFile)) {
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        trustStore.load(trustStoreSteam, trustStorePwd.toCharArray());
        tmf.init(trustStore);
        sslcontext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), new java.security.SecureRandom());
    }
    return sslcontext;
}
```

2) I'm using the "client" to send https request like following:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    public void run(){
        while(true){
            Builder request = client.target(url).request(theString);
            Request request = request.get();
            // other stuffs ...
            Thread.current.sleep(5000);
        }
    }
}).start();
```

3) An Exception throws out in `request.get()`. Notice that there are 3 threads of invocation for `request.get()`, but only one thread successfully gets the response, and other 2 threads get exceptions like the following:

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:287)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:252)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:684)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:681)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:681)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:411)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:311)
    at com.mycode.RequestSender.send(RequestSender.java:37)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1514)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1026)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:961)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1546)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:399)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:285)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1496)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
    ... 36 more
```

It seems like 3 threads try to load the certification when they send request via https, but only 1 thread successes, the other 2 threads cannot find the valid certification path.
But after one request sends successfully, in the next loop after sleeping, all the 3 threads can send request successfully. So the exception only happens in first sending request in multiple-thread context.

So is this a bug in Jersey client or I use it incorrectly ?

Comment: code reformatting and correcting, better code quotes, grammar/syntax corrections

Comment: Did you find any solutions for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bug in Jersey - specifically all latest version (up until 26-b09).
Please see - https://github.com/jersey/jersey/issues/3293

Downgrading to version 2.21.1 resolved this issue for me..